# if else print at the same time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

when I trigger the if condition, why the else will print out as well? someone could indicate what's the problem of the code below? written in JS.

[image: original picture of code]

```js
const rainbow = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue', 'violet'];
let colour = prompt("What is your favourite colour?").toLowerCase();

for (let i = 0; i < rainbow.length; i+=1) {
  if (rainbow[i] === colour) {
    console.log("yes")
  }
  else {
    console.log(rainbow.join(" *** "));
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't post code as image, post the code as text.

Comment: i posted the code as text.

Comment: why do you need a loop if you can do it directly?

Comment: This is working correctly. Its a loop it runs the condition multiple times. Just print nothing in the else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

It's because your loop is running through the array. So for example if I say red it will go to the first if and then after the second iteration it will go to the else. If this code is un a function you need to return in your if, if you want the loop to stop at this moment.

```
const findColor = () => {
    const rainbow = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue', 'violet'];
    let colour = prompt("What is your favourite colour?").toLowerCase();

    for (let i = 0; i < rainbow.length; i+=1) {
      if (rainbow[i] === colour) {
        console.log("yes")
        return rainbow[i]// It will leave the loop when it passes on the right color
      }
      else {
        console.log(rainbow.join(" *** "));
        return
      }
    }
}
```

You can also use the includes function if you don't want to use a loop:

```
console.log(rainbow.includes(colour) ? 'yes' : rainbow.join(" *** "));
```

Comment: you should be using `break` instead of `return`.

Comment: copied my answer without credits 

Comment: i tried to add "return". it gave me an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement"

Comment: @MelodyChen that must be because your code is not a function. Sorry I assumed it was one. I'm gonna edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need a loop for this
You can use the [include](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function for arrays to achieve this.

```js
const rainbow = ['red','orange','yellow','green','cyan','blue','violet']; 
let colour = prompt("What is your favourite colour?").toLowerCase();

console.log(rainbow.includes(colour) ? 'yes' : rainbow.join(" *** "));
```

Comment: Please mark an answer if it woked for you! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method for checking the input.

```js
const rainbow = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue', 'violet'];
let colour = prompt("What is your favourite colour?").toLowerCase();

if (rainbow.includes(colour)) {
  console.log("yes")
}
else {
  console.log(rainbow.join(" *** "));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can break out the loop if you need to when you've found the colour:

```js
const rainbow = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue', 'violet'];

const colour = prompt("What is your favourite colour?").toLowerCase();

for (let i = 0; i < rainbow.length; i+=1) {
  if (rainbow[i] === colour) {
    console.log('yes');
    break;
  } else {
    console.log(rainbow.join(" *** "));
  }
}
```

But a slightly better method would be to remove the loop altogether, and use an array method like [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead.

```js
const rainbow = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue', 'violet'];

const colour = prompt("What is your favourite colour?").toLowerCase();

if (rainbow.includes(colour)) {
  console.log('yes');
} else {
  console.log(rainbow.join(" *** "));
}
```